# executing a command in Dockerfile not working

Tags: dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

# COPY  kube/command.sh .
RUN apt-get update

# To be able to do go run !(*_test).go
RUN apt-get install dnsutils  -y

# CMD [ "shopt -s extglob" ]
CMD [ "sh command.sh" ]
# RUN bash -c shopt -s extglob
# RUN "sh command.sh"
```

Also tried with a script file(command.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

shopt -s extglob
```

And `RUN bash -c shopt -s extglob`

Building Dockerfile I get this:

```
bash: !: event not found
```

If I run the container and manually doing `shopt -s extglob`: it works.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this may help:

```
FROM golang:latest


RUN apt-get update

# To be able to do go run !(*_test).go
RUN apt-get install dnsutils  -y
# COPY  kube/command.sh .
COPY commands.sh /scripts/commands.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/commands.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/commands.sh"]
```